# PDFInfoNotInstalledError AWS Lambda can't find Poppler path with pdf2image

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, poppler

Following the guide here: https://www.petewilcock.com/using-poppler-pdftotext-and-other-custom-binaries-on-aws-lambda/ I was able to get the binaries using EC2. But now for the last step, I cannot seem to find a way to get pdf2image to use the poppler path. Getting error:

```
  "errorMessage": "Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?",
  "errorType": "PDFInfoNotInstalledError",
```

What I've tried:

1. Adding a lambda layer with the package.zip from that guide, then
   calling `convert_from_bytes()` with no poppler_path
2. Adding a lambda layer with the package.zip from that guide, then calling `convert_from_bytes()` with poppler_path = '/opt/lib/'
3. Adding the /lib and /bin directory directly into my lambda and calling `convert_from_bytes()` with poppler_path = '/var/task/lib/'
4. Adding a lambda layer with the package.zip from that guide and adding the environment variable PATH mapped to /opt/ 
    4a. Doing the same thing and mapping it to /opt/lib/

   4b. Doing the same thing and mapping it to /opt/bin/

My lambda for one of the above:

```
import json
import base64
import os
from uuid import uuid4
from pdf2image import convert_from_bytes

POPPLER_PATH = '/opt/lib/'

def text_process_handler(event, context):
    document = bucketHelper.get_bucket_object('<Bucket>', '<document>.pdf')
    images = convert_from_bytes(document,dpi=150, poppler_path=POPPLER_PATH)

    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps({
            "message": "Successful request."
        }),       
    }
```

My `package.zip` looks like:

```
+--lib
|  +--libpoppler.so.70
|  +--libtiff.so.5
|  +--etc...
+--bin
|  +--pdftoppm
|  +--pdftotext
|  +--etc...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Understand The Problem**

Well, I was working on that on that for the previous 2 days, and div even deeply to the pdf2image package to understand why the error happens.

here what causes the error:
the pdf2image python package uses subprocess library to run the binaries like(pdfinfo, pdftocairo, ...etc)

and it's run a Linux command like `pdfinfo /path/to/pdf/file`
and it appears that the binaries when zipped were on `chmod -R 750` (in my case), and that prevents the subprocess library to run the command causing the error "permission denied" which then returns pdf2image package to tell you the same error you face.

> **How to Solve:**

make sure before you zip the binaries that the files mods on 777 by running `chmod -R 777 .`

then when running the method `convert_from_path()` set the `poppler_path` to your binaries distenation.

and that's it

> Note: I create a layer to contain only popplet-utils binaries to use
> in the function.

Comment: What is the `poppler_path` that you specified? And did you test it from `sam local start-api`?

Comment: 1- `poppler_path` is the linux binaries that is required by the python package to run properly, i specified it wherever i put the binaries.

2- no, i test it directly in lambda via aws console.

Comment: Where is that Layer?